# Listen to port continuously and dump data to file

Tags: linux, netcat

I use this command to listen to port and dump data to file:

```
while :  ; do nc -l 0.0.0.0 10000 > log.txt & done
```

First request works perfect, it's dumped in log.txt but after first request, the nc is no longer listening but stopped.

Can someone point me to what I do wrong?

I just want this to run in the background continuously and log any request from this port to log.txt file...

Answer (score 21):

You must add an option to *nc*. The option depends on the version of *nc* you are running. For instance, in my case (Kubuntu), the option is *-k*. From the man page,

> -k      Forces nc to stay listening for another connection after its current connection is completed.  It is
>                an error to use this option without the -l option.

I cannot promise *-k* works (unless you are n Ubuntu, of course), you will have to search for something similar. For instance, on my Debian, *-k* does not exist, but you find:

> -q seconds   after EOF on stdin, wait the specified number of seconds and then quit. If seconds is negative, wait forever

Edit:

To check that it works, on one pc:

```
  nc -k -l 0.0.0.0 10000 > out.txt
```

On a second pc:

```
  echo Hello | nc IP_address_of_first_pc 10000
```

Issue the command above a few times, then interrupt the *nc* command on pc1, check number of lines in out.txt.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed if I put -k it stays and run in the background but the biggest issue is that only first request is dumped into the log file and no other one...

Comment: @CristianBoariu Sorry, I cannot reproduce this error, it works perfectly on my Ubuntu systems. If I just say nc, I get the reply: This is nc from the netcat-openbsd package. An alternative nc is available
in the netcat-traditional package. Do you get the same reply?

Comment: Yes, I receive: "This is nc from the netcat-openbsd package. An alternative nc is available
in the netcat-traditional package.". Basically after I put the command from above I go to a browser and do a GET multiple times to that machine but only first one is logged.

Comment: Are you still using the `while`? With the `-k` you shouln't have to use the `while`. This would be sufficient: `nc -l -k 0.0.0.0 10000 > log.txt`. And if you want to append to log.txt use `nc -l -k 0.0.0.0 10000 >> log.txt`. It could also be a buffering problem where `log.txt` is only written to once in a while. Do a Ctrl+C after sending a couple of messages and see what `log.txt` contains.

Comment: @CristianBoariu See my edit,try it like I did.No buffering problem on my systems.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae It works like this, yes, but why, if I do a GET or POST with Firefox - Poster for instance, it only prints out first request? Is it because it waits for a response?

Comment: @CristianBoariu Did you remember to use the two linefeeds at the end of the request?

Comment: For at least Debian Jessie the `netcat-traditional` version of netcat is bugged and does not keep listening with the `-k` option. Instead, install `netcat-openbsd` and it works again. See also http://serverfault.com/a/457434/135437